# What to use AWS Fargate or AWS Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-fargate

I have a java application that reads from a SQS queue and does some business processing and finally writes it to a datastore. As the SQS queue grows I want to be able to scale to read more messages and process them. Each SQS message will take about 15 to 20 minutes to process. I was looking at a service like AWS Fargate or AWS Beanstalk to deploy my application. Money is not a concern but usability is. What would be the best platform?

Comment: Would you also consider using AWS Lambda? The only potential issue is that Lambda functions can only run for a maximum of 15 minutes. Is your application limited by CPU, disk or memory? (That is, what would let it run faster?)

Comment: Sorry each SQS Message would take 15 to 20 minutes to process. We have tried Lambdas our processes also run into the 3 GB memory limit.

Answer (score 0):

Fargate would be an ideal solution, as it has following advantages over Beanstalk:

1. It's serverless
2. More fine-grained control for custom application architectures.
3. No need to write EB extensions.
4. Build and Test image locally and Promote same to Fargate.
5. With application autoscaling, you can scale on the go.
6. Pricing is per second with a 1-minute minimum

FAQ:
https://aws.amazon.com/fargate/faqs/

Pricing:
https://aws.amazon.com/fargate/pricing/

Answer (score 0):

I've had a very similar use case to this and I used Batch. (which was not available in 2014 when the question was asked)

https://aws.amazon.com/batch/

In my case I was processing audio and video files from the queue.

You can set a lambda to fire on the SQS queue and have that drop the job onto batch for processing.

If you have the minimum cluster size set to zero then you will have no servers running when there is no work to do, but you can have them autoscale up to process as much work as you require when the jobs come in.

The advantage compared to lambda is that the code that executes can be any container with as much resource as you want to throw at it.

For your use case it will be perfect, but for anything that can complete processing in a a few seconds or a minute it's worth making each job process more than one task per execution or all of the time will be spent firing up and shutting down containers.